# SQL Server Agent properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, configuration

I have several dozen servers and would like to be able to check configurations on them ever quarter or so to make sure nothing has changed. I am having difficulty finding how to read a few configurations. Those settings I'm having problems with are in the SQL Server Agent properties:

```
Under the Alert System tab:
   Enable Mail profile
   Mail system
   Mail Profile
   Enable Fail-safe operator
   Operator
   Notify Using

Under the History tab:
   Limit size of job history log
   Remove agent history
```

Hopefully someone can point me in the direction of where I can run a cross server query or better yet powershell query to check all my servers configurations. Thanks!

Comment: Good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181367.aspx.  This article lists all the tables used by SQL Agent.  Out of curiosity, couldn't you just lock down the SQL Agent so no one can make changes without you knowing?  I believe to make those changes you would need to be a member of sysadmin.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my management team wants to allow several people be SAs. Not that I don't trust them, but I just want to make sure nothing accidentally changes :)

Comment: But yes, I've already looked at that list and it is not part of any of those tables.

Comment: Most of these are going to be registry settings which I don't believe have been officially documented. JobHistory can be found as part of sys.dm_server_registry https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204561.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For a "cross-server" query you could set up a [Central Management Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx) and add Registered Servers.